# ¿Cómo añadir con un bucle un elemento de un diccionario?

Tags: python, bucle-for

Un colaborador me ayudó a optimizar un código para evitar la redundancia. Posteriormente hice un bucle en un diccionario, para reemplazar los elementos de una variable, entiendo que iterará sobre los keys y no sobre los values, entiendo que imprime 1, 2, 3 que son los valores que toma.

Para iterar los valores los evalué:

```
elementos={1: 'mat_columnas', 
           2: 'mat_trabes', 
           3: 'mat_losas'}


for i in elementos.values():
    print(i)
    pesos, bolsas = calculo(i, 4*0.8*0.8)
    print (pesos, bolsas)
```

Pero no funciona porque me arroja **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'**

Código completo:

```
elementos={1: 'mat_columnas', 
           2: 'mat_trabes', 
           3: 'mat_losas'}

mat_columnas = dict(
    cemento=350 * 1.05,
    arena=0.56,
    grava=0.84,
    agua=180,
    cal=68) # Estos datos son por default
mat_trabes = dict(
    cemento=360,
    arena=0.56,
    grava=0.84,
    agua=200,
    cal=68) # Estos datos son por default
mat_losas = dict(
    cemento=351,
    arena=0.56,
    grava=0.84,
    agua=180,
    cal=68) # Estos datos son por default

def calculo(materiales, volumen):
    peso_individual = {key: volumen * value for key, value in materiales.items()}
    bolsas = (peso_individual["cemento"] / 50)
    return peso_individual, bolsas

for i in elementos.values():
    print(i)
    pesos, bolsas = calculo.replace(i, 4*0.8*0.8)
    print (pesos, bolsas)
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto? Agradezco mucho su ayuda, saludos!

Comment: Lo que pasa es que en la función calculo, el parámetro que recibe en materiales no es una lista ni un diccionario, por lo que no tiene la propiedad `items()` el valor que recibe es lo que tiene la ieteracion que haces antes ejemplo `mat_columnas`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes tres diccionarios con los materiales. Ahora pon esos tres diccionarios en una lista:

```
elementos = [mat_columnas, mat_trabes, mat_losas]
```

e itera sobre ella:

```
for materiales in elementos:
```

En cada iteración calculas el total de materiales pasando el diccionario recibido en `materiales`

```
pesos, bolsas = calculo(materiales, 4*0.8*0.8)
```

**Demo**

```
mat_columnas = dict(
    cemento=350 * 1.05,
    arena=0.56,
    grava=0.84,
    agua=180,
    cal=68) # Estos datos son por default
mat_trabes = dict(
    cemento=360,
    arena=0.56,
    grava=0.84,
    agua=200,
    cal=68) # Estos datos son por default
mat_losas = dict(
    cemento=351,
    arena=0.56,
    grava=0.84,
    agua=180,
    cal=68) # Estos datos son por default

def calculo(materiales, volumen):
    peso_individual = {key: volumen * value for key, value in materiales.items()}
    bolsas = (peso_individual["cemento"] / 50)
    return peso_individual, bolsas

elementos = [mat_columnas, mat_trabes, mat_losas]
for materiales in elementos:
    print(materiales)
    pesos, bolsas = calculo(materiales, 4*0.8*0.8)
    print (pesos, bolsas)
```

produce

```
{'cemento': 367.5, 'arena': 0.56, 'grava': 0.84, 'agua': 180, 'cal': 68}
{'cemento': 940.8000000000002, 'arena': 1.4336000000000004, 'grava': 2.1504000000000003, 'agua': 460.80000000000007, 'cal': 174.08000000000004} 18.816000000000003
{'cemento': 360, 'arena': 0.56, 'grava': 0.84, 'agua': 200, 'cal': 68}
{'cemento': 921.6000000000001, 'arena': 1.4336000000000004, 'grava': 2.1504000000000003, 'agua': 512.0000000000001, 'cal': 174.08000000000004} 18.432000000000002
{'cemento': 351, 'arena': 0.56, 'grava': 0.84, 'agua': 180, 'cal': 68}
{'cemento': 898.5600000000002, 'arena': 1.4336000000000004, 'grava': 2.1504000000000003, 'agua': 460.80000000000007, 'cal': 174.08000000000004} 17.971200000000003
```